# Python Json data

Tags: python

I have looked all over the place trying to find what is probably trivial but I just cant wrap my head around how to do this. I have a web service that wants data to look like this to update some objects: ( this is encoded into the POST body of the web service call)

```
{
    "name":zone_name,
    "service":{
            "name":"service_name",
             "dns_address_record_list":[{
                        "vip_order":"record",
                        "static":"state",
                    }
                        {
                        "vip_order":"record",
                        "static":"state",}
                  ]
              }
          }
```

I am trying to build methods so that I can add to the `dns_address_record_list[]` programmatically based on a user form. How can I generate the above data dynamically and add to the `dns_address_record_list"[]`? I have tried all kinds of things but nothing works.

Any pointers a greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I have tried all kinds of things but nothing works.* For example?

Answer (score 1):

It's a list. So you use [list methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types).

```
>>> foo = [1, 2, 3]
>>> foo.append(5)
>>> foo
[1, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: but this is a list off dictionary objects so how do you append dictionaries to a list ??

Comment: so inside this list I may have many dictionaries that look like {vip-order:value}

Comment: Uh... pass a dictionary... `foo.append({'bar': 42})`

Comment: uh.. So maybe I am missing something but this is not just a list. This is mutliple dictionaries with a list inside and more dictionaries. Appologize for newbie questions but I am just trying to understand the logic. If it were as simple as adding a dictionary to a list, I wouldnt be asking here.

Comment: First you index the structure to get to the list, and then you mutate the list.

Comment: yes I know how to get at elements of a list. I had already tried feeding dictionaries as parameters in my method and then appending to the list. Still no go...  So let me make sure I am not hosing something else up somewhere else.

Comment: wow okay so this was very trivial as I suspected. I was appending the dictionaries to the list but I had placed another set of [] around the list in the data that was being sent in the POST.  Sometimes I hesitate to ask questions as if you look at it long enough, you can eventually get it... Anyway thanks for the response I appreciate the pointers.